# order_by() is not working properly for distance range data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data for distance in range like

5-10, 0-5 , 10-15,

I am using this query to get data in sorted order:

```
$this->db->select("distance_from_mall");
$this->db->from("transport_charges");
$this->db->order_by("distance_from_mall", "asc");
$route =$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

it gives me

0-5 , 10-15,5-10  instead of   0-5 ,5-10, 10-15,

Comment: That's because MySQL will order by name, not numeric. So the result you get is precisely what you requested (0, 1, 5).

Comment: `CAST(distance_from_mall AS UNSIGNED)`

Comment: Post your comment as answer Daan. It's what the OP needs :)

Comment: @Allendar not sure how it works in CI

Comment: yes @Allendar, You are right.
but how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: To pass by all the quotations that Active Record places on your parameters you could just custom query it: `$this->db->query("SELECT distance_from_mall FROM transport_changes ORDER BY CAST(distance_from_mall AS UNSIGNED) ASC");`

Answer (score 1):

Because your distance is a string, the engine `ORDER`s it as a string.

That is the correct response for this query.

I'd suggest changing the `distance` to the minimum integer/numeric for each `transport_charge`.. this will give you all the data you need if the ranges don't overlap.

If they do; store the `distance` as two columns, `range_max` and `range_min`, and `ORDER BY` whichever makes more sense or both columns separately: `ORDER BY range_min, range_max`

Comment: That's not necessary.

Comment: @Daan Not strictly, but it is advisable if you want to do any calculations, aggregations or filtering on the distance in a sensible query. Indexing would be a nightmare too.

Comment: Is it not possible using a single column ?

Comment: @Sujeet Yes it is possible, if the ranges don't overlap. See my answer, paragraph 3. I wouldn't worry about an extra column though if they do.. the two values are two separate pieces of data so belong in two columns.